# What's the equivalent of Jasmine browser debugging for Jest testing in React while using TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, debugging, jestjs

**Situation:**

I have a project that has a series of *[Jest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jest_(framework))* tests. I want to run them in debug mode preferably so that:

- The tests run in the browser
- I can use [dev tools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_development_tools) to set breakpoints, set actual, and see expected values
- execute JavaScript code in dev tools while the test is running
- if able, see the tests render in the browser as they run

There should be a way to do it without having to run the debugger through Visual Studio Code.

When I've worked on [Jasmine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jasmine_(JavaScript_testing_framework)) and [Karma](https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma) tests in the past, you would set up a few configuration files:

**karma.conf.js**

```
customLaunchers: {
   Chrome_with_debugging: {
     base: 'Chrome',
     flags: ['--remote-debugging-port=9222'],
     debug: true
}}
```

**launch.json**

```
{
    "name": "Debug tests",
    "type": "chrome",
    "request": "attach",
    "port": 9222,
    "sourceMaps": true,
    "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}"
}
```

You would then execute *ng test --browsers Chrome_with_debugging* and it allows you to debug right in Visual Studio Code as the test runs in the browser.

There was another way where you could execute the code in `yarn run test 'testName' --debug` (or something like it) and it would pull up the browser.

**What I've tried:**

- I've tried opening the test file in Chrome and setting a breakpoint through dev tools, but the code is compiled and it's not easy to follow. None of variable names stay consistent and the file looks totally different.
- I remember when I did this previously I think I may have used the Node.js [Webpack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webpack), but I'm not remembering if I did or not.
- I tried adding DEBUG statements in Visual Studio Code (which isn't ideal; I'd rather debug through the browser), but it never hits them.

Comment: I am not the one who down vote you, but I notice you were using tag "visual-studio-debugging", I think that tag is for VS Tools like VS2022. I changed the tag, that maybe the reason. :)

Comment: Why would that be the reason when this was done with a VSTool until they deprecated it recently.